# Bash non greedy replace

Tags: bash

Say I have a string

```
foo='teledunet&file=rotana_aflam&provider=rtmp&autostart=true&'
```

If I wanted to cut out the `file` parameter I could do

```
$ echo ${foo/&file=[^&]*}
teledunet
```

but as you can see the search is being greedy and taking the rest of the string. Can it be made to replace non-greedy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo ${foo/&file*([^&])}
teledunet&provider=rtmp&autostart=true&
```

You may have to `shopt -s extglob` to enable extended glob syntax first.